# how can I prove field-grouping functionality(tuple with same field goes to same task)?

Tags: apache-storm

I'm a fresher of Storm, I'm getting started with Storm using the project [storm-starter](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter). In this project there is a Topology called `WordCountTopology`, the key code for building topology is:

```
builder.setBolt("split", new SplitSentence(), 8).shuffleGrouping("spout");
builder.setBolt("count", new WordCount(), 12).fieldsGrouping("split", new Fields("word"));
```

and in the implementation of WordCount bolt, the key method `execute` is:

```
@Override
public void execute(Tuple tuple, BasicOutputCollector collector) {
  String word = tuple.getString(0);
  Integer count = counts.get(word);
  if (count == null)
    count = 0;
  count++;
  counts.put(word, count);
  collector.emit(new Values(word, count));
}
```

**My Question is:**

As the functionality of filed-grouping is that: tuples with the same filed `word` will go to the same task for post processing. Here "task" means thread, how can I prove this functionality? In addition, in my opinion, the logic in method `execute` is a little awkward. In a single task, the parameter `tuple` is always the same, but in the `execute` method it does not reflect this, in other words, the logic dose not use this convenience.

Am I clear? **My point is that**, the code here in `execute` is not taking the feature of filed-grouping into account, the code here can also be applied to the situation of shuffle-grouping.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to site few points, it might help clear your doubts

> Here "task" means thread

In storm's terminology tasks are `NOT` threads but they are responsible for processing the actual logic.  *Each spout or bolt that you implement in your code executes as many tasks across the cluster*.  So you can define them as an running instance of the components i.e Spouts or Bolts. 

There is another entity called `Executors` which are the thread responsible for running  these tasks.It can run one or multiple tasks of the same component. An executor having multiple tasks actually is saying the same component is executed for multiple times by the executor.

Now coming back to your question

> the code here in execute is not taking the feature of filed-grouping into account, the code here can also be applied to the situation of shuffle-grouping

In very brief `A fields grouping lets you group a stream by a subset of its fields`, meaning  in order to do a word count, if we filtered the stream by using fieldsGrouping on a field name 'first_name` then it is expected that all the first_name field with a value say (Foo) should go to the same task, and the same field with a different value (Bar) goes to another task.

So here the `execute` method is supposed to receive the same field value and thus can easily update its counter and to do that it does not require to consider anything special. The whole logic is written keeping in mind that the bolt will be chained with the proper data and that's why using the proper grouping become such an important thing. So if you use `shuffleGrouping` then same code will run but produces incorrect data.

Comment: if all the first_name field with value 'Foo' go to the same task, can I change the logic of `execute` method to this: set a member variable of WordCount bolt named `time` with initial value 0, in execute method, increase `time` by 1. Now if `time == 1`, that means this is the first time we receive a word from spout, extract the value(Foo), store the value to a member variable(like `word`), assign count = 1, else if `time > 1`, we do not need to extract the value again, cause the value is Foo, we directly make `count++`. I think this is taking the feature into account more directly.

Comment: You are assuming that the statement "All tuples with the value Foo will go to the same bolt" also extrapolates to "All tuples going to this bolt will have the value Foo". That isn't correct. A given bolt will receive many tuples with many different values for the grouped fields, the guarantee is that all the tuples with the same values for the grouped fields will go to the same bolt.

Answer (score 1):

Well Pinky (or anyone else who finds this useful), to **prove** it, you just have to keep track of the bolt or spout task ID:

```
@Override
public void prepare(Map map, TopologyContext tc, OutputCollector oc) {
  this.boltId = tc.getThisTaskId();
}
```

Now in the execute() of the same fieldsGrouped bolt that receives the tuples, you just print the id and the tuple:

```
@Override
public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
  String myWord = (String) tuple.getValue(0);
  System.out.println("word: "+myWord+" boltID:"+boltId);
}
```